# production build removing share

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

I'm using RXjs 6.5.2, and using .share() to multicast the several of my data calls. It all works perfectly fine `ng build --extract-css --watch`, 
but when running with the prod switch `ng build --extract-css --prod` I get the error ".pipe(...).share is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are also using rxjs-compat in your project. In `RxJS 5.5.2` they moved share to be a pipe operator, ironically so it can be tree shaken more effectively. If you instead use

```
<Observable>.pipe(share());
```

You will get the correct tree-shaken code.